Conditional Fatou's lemma and integrability
Here they prove the conditional expectation version of Fatou's lemma:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Conditional_Fatou%27s_Lemma
It says almost the same as ordinary Fatour's lemma that
$E[\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n|\mathcal{G}]\le \liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}E[X_n|\mathcal{G}]$ a.s.
In ordinary measure theory we allow integrals to have infinite expectation. But when we talk about conditional expectation it is assume that the expectation must be finite. So for the quantity $E[\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n|\mathcal{G}]$ to exist, do we have to also assume that $E[|\liminf\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}X_n|]<\infty$? Is this a necessairy condition to use conditional Fatou's lemma?, because this is not something we "get for free"?

$E[X|\mathcal G]$ can defined for any non-negative r.v. $X$ and no extra integrability condition is required for conditional Fatou's Lemma.
